Java Spring Boot Rest API take use Bearer Token on POST Route
I am currently learning Java Spring. To learn it I am creating an API. The API has the following functions:

User can register an account with name, email and password
User can sign in with email and password, and will get a Bearer Token back
User can create interests by sending the Bearer Token and a interest description.

I have created a diagram of it below.

Help
I need help with creating a "interest" at the route
/api/interests.
I do not know how to handle the Bearer Token.
This is the function that somehow needs to take in the Bearer Token:
@PostMapping
@PreAuthorize("isAuthenticated()") // Requires authentication
public Interest createInterest(@AuthenticationPrincipal User user, @RequestBody String interestName) {
    System.out.println("InterestController()::createInterest()::user=" + user.toString() + " interestName=" + interestName);
    return interestService.createInterest(user, interestName);
}

TravelApplication.java
/**
 * src/main/java/com/ekeberg/travel/TravelApplication.java
 *
 * The main application class for the Travel application.
 *
 * Author: ditlef9
 */

package com.ekeberg.travel;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.CorsRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurer;

@SpringBootApplication
public class TravelApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(TravelApplication.class, args);

    }


    // Allow http://localhost to 8080
    @Bean
    public WebMvcConfigurer corsConfigurer() {
        return new WebMvcConfigurer() {
            @Override
            public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
                registry.addMapping("/**") // Allow all endpoints
                        .allowedOrigins("http://localhost:3000") // Allow the specific origin
                        .allowedMethods("*") // Allow all methods (GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS)
                        .allowedHeaders("*"); // Allow all headers
            }
        };
    }

}

config/SecurityConfig.java
/**
 * java/com/ekeberg/travel/config/SecurityConfig.java
 *
 * Configures Spring Security settings, allowing or restricting access to specific endpoints
 * and managing the overall security filter chain.
 *
 * Controls security rules like authentication and authorization and integrates Spring Security
 * into the application, providing secure access to endpoints.
 * 
 * Author: ditlef9
 */
package com.ekeberg.travel.config;

import com.ekeberg.travel.security.JwtUtil;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.configuration.AuthenticationConfiguration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {

    private final JwtUtil jwtUtil;

    public SecurityConfig(JwtUtil jwtUtil) {
        this.jwtUtil = jwtUtil;
    }

    @Bean
    public BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager(AuthenticationConfiguration authConfig) throws Exception {
        return authConfig.getAuthenticationManager();
    }


    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests(authorizeRequests ->
                        authorizeRequests.anyRequest().permitAll() // Allow all requests without authentication
                )
                .csrf(csrf -> csrf.disable()); // Disable CSRF protection for all requests

        return http.build();
    }
}

security/JwtUtil.java
/**
 * java/com/ekeberg/travel/security/JwtUtil.java
 *
 * A utility class for generating and validating JSON Web Tokens (JWTs) using the HS256 algorithm.
 *
 * Generates JWTs that enable stateless, token-based authentication,
 * ensuring users can access resources securely without maintaining server-side sessions.
 *
 * Author: ditlef9
 */
package com.ekeberg.travel.security;

import io.jsonwebtoken.Jwts;
import io.jsonwebtoken.SignatureAlgorithm;
import io.jsonwebtoken.security.Keys;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import javax.crypto.SecretKey;
import java.util.Date;

@Component
public class JwtUtil {

    // Generate a secure key for HS256 using Keys.secretKeyFor
    private final SecretKey SECRET_KEY = Keys.secretKeyFor(SignatureAlgorithm.HS256);

    public String generateToken(String email) {
        return Jwts.builder()
                .setSubject(email)
                .setIssuedAt(new Date())
                .setExpiration(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + 1000 * 60 * 60 * 10)) // 10 hours
                .signWith(SECRET_KEY)  // Use the generated secure key here
                .compact();
    }
}

interest/Interest.java
/**
 * java/com/ekeberg/travel/interest/Interest.java
 *
 * Represents an interest or hobby associated with a user.
 * Each interest has a name and is linked to a specific user.
 *
 * Author: ditlef9
 */
package com.ekeberg.travel.interest;

import com.ekeberg.travel.user.User;
import jakarta.persistence.*;

@Entity(name="interests")
public class Interest {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private String name;  // Name or description of the interest

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", nullable = false)
    private User user; // The user associated with this interest

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public User getUser() {
        return user;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void setUser(User user) {
        this.user = user;
    }
}

interest/InterestController.java
/**
 * java/com/ekeberg/travel/interest/InterestController.java
 *
 * REST API Controller for managing user interests.
 * Provides endpoints for creating, listing, updating, and deleting interests.
 * Requires user authentication to access.
 *
 * Author: ditlef9
 */

package com.ekeberg.travel.interest;

import com.ekeberg.travel.user.User;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.security.access.prepost.PreAuthorize;
import org.springframework.security.core.annotation.AuthenticationPrincipal;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

import java.util.List;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/interests")
public class InterestController {

    private final InterestService interestService;

    @Autowired
    public InterestController(InterestService interestService) {
        this.interestService = interestService;
    }

    /**
     * Lists all interests associated with the authenticated user.
     * Requires the user to be authenticated.
     */
    @GetMapping
    @PreAuthorize("isAuthenticated()") // Requires authentication
    public List<Interest> listInterests(@AuthenticationPrincipal User user) {
        return interestService.listInterests(user);
    }

    /**
     * Creates a new interest for the authenticated user.
     * Requires the user to be authenticated.
     */
    @PostMapping
    @PreAuthorize("isAuthenticated()") // Requires authentication
    public Interest createInterest(@AuthenticationPrincipal User user, @RequestBody String interestName) {
        System.out.println("InterestController()::createInterest()::user=" + user.toString() + " interestName=" + interestName);
        return interestService.createInterest(user, interestName);
    }

    /**
     * Updates the name of an existing interest.
     * Requires the user to be authenticated.
     */
    @PutMapping("/{id}")
    @PreAuthorize("isAuthenticated()") // Requires authentication
    public Interest updateInterest(@PathVariable Long id, @RequestBody String newName) {
        return interestService.updateInterest(id, newName);
    }

    /**
     * Deletes an interest by its ID.
     * Requires the user to be authenticated.
     */
    @DeleteMapping("/{id}")
    @PreAuthorize("isAuthenticated()") // Requires authentication
    public void deleteInterest(@PathVariable Long id) {
        interestService.deleteInterest(id);
    }
}

interest/InterestRepository.java
/**
 * java/com/ekeberg/travel/interest/InterestRepository.java
 *
 * Repository for managing Interest data.
 * Provides database access methods for the Interest entity.
 *
 * Author: ditlef9
 */
package com.ekeberg.travel.interest;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;

import java.util.List;

public interface InterestRepository extends JpaRepository<Interest, Long> {
    List<Interest> findByUserId(Long userId); // Find interests associated with a specific user ID
}

interest/InterestService.java
/**
 * java/com/ekeberg/travel/interest/InterestService.java
 *
 * Service layer for managing interests.
 * Provides business logic for creating, listing, updating, and deleting interests.
 *
 * Author: ditlef9
 */

package com.ekeberg.travel.interest;

import com.ekeberg.travel.user.User;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import java.util.List;

@Service
public class InterestService {

    private final InterestRepository interestRepository;

    public InterestService(InterestRepository interestRepository) {
        this.interestRepository = interestRepository;
    }

    /**
     * Retrieves all interests associated with a user.
     */
    public List<Interest> listInterests(User user) {
        return interestRepository.findByUserId(user.getId());
    }

    /**
     * Creates a new interest for the specified user.
     */
    public Interest createInterest(User user, String interestName) {
        Interest interest = new Interest();
        interest.setName(interestName);
        interest.setUser(user);
        return interestRepository.save(interest);
    }

    /**
     * Updates an existing interest's name.
     */
    public Interest updateInterest(Long interestId, String newName) {
        Interest interest = interestRepository.findById(interestId)
                .orElseThrow(() -> new RuntimeException("Interest not found"));
        interest.setName(newName);
        return interestRepository.save(interest);
    }

    /**
     * Deletes an interest by its ID.
     */
    public void deleteInterest(Long interestId) {
        interestRepository.deleteById(interestId);
    }
}

user/User.java
/**
 * java/com/ekeberg/travel/user/User.java
 *
 * Represents the application's user entity, including fields for email, name, and 
 * password.
 *
 * Provides a structure for persisting and managing user data within the database,
 * serving as the main user record.
 *
 * Author: ditlef9
 */
package com.ekeberg.travel.user;

import jakarta.persistence.*;


@Entity(name="users")
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(unique = true, nullable = false)
    private String email;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String name;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String password;

    private String token; // New field for the JWT token

    // Constructors, getters, and setters
    public User() {}

    public User(String email, String name, String password) {
        this.email = email;
        this.name = name;
        this.password = password;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String getToken() {
        return token; // Getter for token
    }

    public void setToken(String token) {
        this.token = token; // Setter for token
    }
}

user/UserController.java
    /**
     * java/com/ekeberg/travel/user/UserController.java
     *
     * A REST controller that handles HTTP requests for user-related operations (e.g., sign-up, sign-in, change password).
     *
     * Exposes user management endpoints to clients, acting as an entry point for user authentication and account actions.
     *
     * Author: ditlef9
     */
    
    package com.ekeberg.travel.user;
    
    import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;
    
    import java.util.Map;
    
    @RestController
    @RequestMapping("/api/users")
    public class UserController {
    
        private final UserService userService;
    
        public UserController(UserService userService) {
            this.userService = userService;
        }
    
        @PostMapping("/sign-up")
        public ResponseEntity<?> signUp(@RequestBody Map<String, String> signUpData) {
            String email = signUpData.get("email");
            String name = signUpData.get("name");
            String password = signUpData.get("password");
    
            System.out.println("UserController()::signUp()::email=" + email + " name=" + name + " password=(hidden)");
            User user = userService.signUpUserService(email, name, password);
            return ResponseEntity.ok("User registered with email: " + user.getEmail());
        }
    
        @PostMapping("/sign-in")
        public ResponseEntity<?> signIn(@RequestBody Map<String, String> loginData) {
            String email = loginData.get("email");
            String password = loginData.get("password");
    
            System.out.println("UserController()::signIn()::email=" + email + " password=(hidden)");
    
            // Retrieve user information and token
            User user = userService.signInUserService(email, password);
            if (user == null) {
                return ResponseEntity.status(401).body("Invalid credentials");
            }
    
            String token = user.getToken(); // Assuming your User object has a method to get the token
            // Create a response object to return user ID, name, and token
            Map<String, Object> response = Map.of(
                    "userId", user.getId(),      // Get the user ID from the user object
                    "name", user.getName(),      // Get the user name from the user object
                    "token", "Bearer " + token    // Format the token as Bearer token
            );
    
            return ResponseEntity.ok(response); // Return the response object
        }
    
        @PutMapping("/change-password")
        public ResponseEntity<?> changePassword(@RequestParam Long userId, @RequestParam String newPassword) {
            userService.changePassword(userId, newPassword);
            return ResponseEntity.ok("Password changed successfully");
        }
    
        @DeleteMapping("/{userId}")
        public ResponseEntity<?> deleteUser(@PathVariable Long userId) {
            userService.deleteUser(userId);
            return ResponseEntity.ok("User deleted successfully");
        }
    }

**user/UserRepository.java**

/**
 * java/com/ekeberg/travel/user/UserRepository.java
 *
 * A Spring Data JPA repository interface for performing database operations on
 * User entities.
 *
 * Simplifies database interactions, allowing CRUD operations on user data without
 * writing SQL, and supports custom queries like finding users by email.
 *
 * Author: ditlef9
 */
package com.ekeberg.travel.user;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;

import java.util.Optional;

public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {
    Optional<User> findByEmail(String email);
}

user/UserService.java
/**
 * java/com/ekeberg/travel/user/UserService.java
 *
 * Defines the contract for user-related business logic, such as registration,
 * login, and password management.
 *
 * Serves as an abstraction layer, separating business logic from data access,
 * making the application more modular and maintainable.
 *
 * Author: ditlef9
 */

package com.ekeberg.travel.user;

public interface UserService {
    User signUpUserService(String email, String name, String password);
    User signInUserService(String email, String password);
    void changePassword(Long userId, String newPassword);
    void deleteUser(Long userId);
}

user/UserServiceImpl.java
/**
 * java/com/ekeberg/travel/user/UserServiceImpl.java
 *
 * Implements UserService, providing concrete logic for registering users,
 * validating logins, and managing passwords.
 *
 * Contains the core functionality of user management, ensuring user data is
 * processed securely and integrates with JwtUtil to generate tokens for logged-in users.
 *
 * UserServiceImpl implements UserService means that UserServiceImpl is following a set of rules defined by UserService.
 * The UserService interface is like a blueprint or contract, and it helps keep the program flexible.
 *
 * Auhtor: ditlef9
 */

package com.ekeberg.travel.user;


import com.ekeberg.travel.security.JwtUtil;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService {

    private final UserRepository userRepository;
    private final BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;
    private final JwtUtil jwtUtil;

    public UserServiceImpl(UserRepository userRepository, BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder, JwtUtil jwtUtil) {
        this.userRepository = userRepository;
        this.passwordEncoder = passwordEncoder;
        this.jwtUtil = jwtUtil;
    }

    @Override
    public User signUpUserService(String email, String name, String password) {
        if (userRepository.findByEmail(email).isPresent()) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Email already in use");
        }
        String encodedPassword = passwordEncoder.encode(password);
        User newUser = new User(email, name, encodedPassword);
        return userRepository.save(newUser);
    }

    @Override
    public User signInUserService(String email, String password) {
        // Find user by email. userRepository.findByEmail should return an Optional<User>
        User user = userRepository.findByEmail(email)
                .orElseThrow(() -> new RuntimeException("Invalid email or password")); // Throw exception if user not found

        // Check if the provided password matches the stored password
        if (passwordEncoder.matches(password, user.getPassword())) {
            String token = jwtUtil.generateToken(user.getEmail()); // Assuming generateToken(user) returns a JWT token
            user.setToken(token); // Set the token in the user object
            return user; // Return the user object with all necessary details
        }

        // If the password doesn't match, throw an exception
        throw new RuntimeException("Invalid email or password");
    }

    @Override
    public void changePassword(Long userId, String newPassword) {
        User user = userRepository.findById(userId)
                .orElseThrow(() -> new RuntimeException("User not found"));
        user.setPassword(passwordEncoder.encode(newPassword));
        userRepository.save(user);
    }

    @Override
    public void deleteUser(Long userId) {
        userRepository.deleteById(userId);
    }
}

application.properties
# resources/application.properties

# Spring
spring.application.name=travel

# PostgreSQL
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/travel-dev
spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.password=root
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect

# JWT
jwt.secret=NGTr5IxoO6Nq6X3Kcy6s9FYtjLJ3H3+6R7b7H0HhDgM=
jwt.expiration=3600000  # Token expiration time in milliseconds (e.g., 1 hour)

build.gradle.kts
plugins {
    java
    id("org.springframework.boot") version "3.3.5"
    id("io.spring.dependency-management") version "1.1.6"
}

group = "com.ekeberg"
version = "0.0.1-SNAPSHOT"

java {
    toolchain {
        languageVersion = JavaLanguageVersion.of(23)
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    // Spring Boot starters
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-validation")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security") // For Spring Security
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa") // For JPA support

    // PostgreSQL Driver
    runtimeOnly("org.postgresql:postgresql")

    // Development tools
    developmentOnly("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools")

    // JWT Support (optional but useful for JWT token handling)
    implementation("io.jsonwebtoken:jjwt-api:0.11.5")
    runtimeOnly("io.jsonwebtoken:jjwt-impl:0.11.5")
    runtimeOnly("io.jsonwebtoken:jjwt-jackson:0.11.5") // for JSON serialization

    // Swagger Docs
    implementation("org.springdoc:springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui:2.1.0")


    // Testing
    testImplementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test")
    testImplementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-testcontainers")
    testImplementation("org.testcontainers:junit-jupiter")
    testRuntimeOnly("org.junit.platform:junit-platform-launcher")
}

tasks.withType<Test> {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}


you  need help to create an interest to what? can you narrow down a question? please be more specific. this branch of SO is not for code review.

I need help with creating a "interest" at the route /api/interests. I do not know how to handle the Bearer Token.

do all those texts you'd posted relate to your issue?

What  do you want to do actually what bearer token? Just you need it or anything else? @Europa

I don't see a question

It seems you want to implement some form of OpenID authentication to your application. When doing this, the first rule is always: don't try to reinvent the wheel. Please take a look at existing Authentication solutions like keycloak, for example.
Also, if your controller methods need to access the access token, you probably are validating the token in the wrong place. Using Spring Security would be a much better way of doing this.
